# How to get timezone on Android device?

Tags: java, android, timezone, locale, utc

I got this list of time zone:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Is there any way I can get the TZ value of this list on Android device? I am not really sure what it is called in Android.

Or if anyone can point me to the right direction please? I am quite confused atm.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android Developer reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html

If you want to get TimeZone-TZ, use `TimeZone.getID()`.

```
TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
String name = timeZone.getID();  // "Asia/Seoul"
```

Comment: It's not working for me. Result is always UTC